# Как на Яндекс карте при клике перейти к ближайшему дому?

Tags: яндекс-карты

Как на Яндекс карте при клике перейти к ближайшему дому?

Comment: Опишите подробнее, что вы хотите сделать и какое поведение получить. 
Это вопрос про API, Конструктор, виджеты или сам сервис Яндекс.Карты?

Comment: Это вопрос про API и javascript

Comment: Получив координаты щелчка, как-то перейти к ближайшему дому по этим координатам.

Comment: Поиск ближайшего объекта по документации Яндекса делается так: https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/jsbox/2.1/find_closest_object

Comment: А как сделать поиск ближайшего дома?

Answer (score 2):

При обратном геокодировании (поиск адреса по координатам) можно указать тип искомого объекта [в параметре `kind`](https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/doc/jsapi/2.1/ref/reference/geocode-docpage/?from=SO#param-options.kind). В вашем случае можно геокодировать координаты клика по карте, указав `kind: 'house'` - в ответе будет адрес ближайшего дома к точке. Если вблизи точки клика зданий нет, ответ геокодера будет пустым.

[Пример обратного геокодирования в песочнице](https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/jsbox/2.1/reverse_geocode?from=SO)